# Delay actions in android

Tags: android

I want to change the image in `imageView` after 5 seconds from app start.

This is the code that I tried so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView screen;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    screen=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    screen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use a `Handler`, such as:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // change image
    }

}, 5000); // 5000ms delay
```

As Sam says in the comments, you could also do this (because all `View`s have their own handler):

```
screen.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // change image
    }

}, 5000); // 5000ms delay
```

See the [Handler Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)).

Comment: You don't even need to create a new Handler. Every View has one built-in and access it with `screen.post()` or `screen.postDelayed()`.

Comment: @Sam how do i set the time in screen.postDelayed() ??

Answer (score 3):

you can try thread like this:

```
 new Thread(){  
        public void run(){  
            //sleep(5000);
            //refreshSthHere();
        }  
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Handler like Tom Leese said or Java Timer

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // this code will be executed after 2 seconds       
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Is this working with GUI actions ? Because GUI actions have to run on the GUI thread in my memory.

Comment: you have to add inside the run of TimerTask       activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                
            }
        });